# Error 404 with JSP and Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

is the form tag in my JSP

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminFacultyLogin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AdminFacultyLogin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminFacultyLogin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>adminPackage.AdminFacultyLogin</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

are the ones in my servlet

Hi i would like to create a login page for my application. I have a JSP and a servlet. My JSP page has two forms. When I click on the submit button it says Error 404. I have the servlet. I checked web.xml for servlet mapping. I found that the servlet mapping is perfect. I couldn't figure out the reason behind error 404

Comment: What did you request to the server? You get 404 error when the server could not find what was requested.

Comment: Thanks Prudhvi, I figured out the issue. The request dispatcher link was not a valid one in the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request dispatcher link was not a valid one in the servlet.